# Pass parameter from page to ActiveX

Tags: asp.net, html, activex

```
    <object id="Bacs_DBTableRepX"
     classid="CLSID:CA8B72B3-3B15-40D7-9364-478E25AF5B41"
     codebase="Bacs_DBTableRepX.cab"
        style="
        Z-INDEX: 102; LEFT: 20px; WIDTH: 1200px; 
        POSITION: absolute; TOP: 80px; HEIGHT: 600px">
        <param name="ax_Command" value='<%=GetText()%>'/>
    </object>
```

Here is my try but it made no sense. Parameter had not being sent.

Is there any examples how to sent parameter to my ActiveX or some mistakes in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html code looks like correct, here is a sample:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp

I would try to set a breakpoint to the property **getter** and check whether it is called. Getters are always called before setters during control initialization. If it is not called, probably you forgot to add your prop to property map or something like that…

Comment: Yes ! property map , how to add them there ? (p.s. also how to make it without Class Explorer - There is no Class Explorer on Nemerle Integration >_< )

Comment: I am not familiar with Nemerle, but I advise you to retag the question with "Nemerle" tag or ask another more specific one.