# How to add property to property map without class explorer?

Tags: asp.net, object, activex, nemerle

I've got a new question after answer on this question [Pass parameter from page to ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816294/pass-parameter-from-page-to-activex)

How to add property to property map without class explorer?

Need to add the property for object and class explorer doesn't work because Nemerle doesn't support it yet.

Code:

```
<object id="DBTableRepX"
 classid="CLSID:CA8B72B3-3B15-40D7-9364-478E25AF5B41"
 codebase="DBTableRepX.cab"
    style="
    Z-INDEX: 102; LEFT: 20px; WIDTH: 1200px; 
    POSITION: absolute; TOP: 80px; HEIGHT: 600px">
    <param name="ax_Command" value='<%=GetText()%>'/>
</object>
```

Comment: Is your GetText() method marked as public?

Comment: @CheckRaise I can't be sure it was on May 2010, but I hope so.

Comment: I didn't even check the date of the post but I find it interesting that it's the top question on the unanswered tab.  Assumed it was a recent post :p

Comment: So I still remember there was some ActiveX and I need to transfer property there but it's more Nemerle and property map related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not derive you own ActiveX class from the one you are using and add the property to the derived class?

Or make a wrapper class and use that.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can have a sources of the ActiveX... Can I still do it?

Comment: yes, you can.  Souce code is not needed for a wrapper class nor deriving from it.  Your own class will need to be an ActiveX control in it own right.  Not elegant and a bit clunky, though possible.

Comment: But I still not fully understand the idea. You say "add the property to the derived class" but there is the same trouble, no class explorer there.

Comment: Add the property to source code for the derived class, as you would do for any class that you define.

Comment: @nCdy Where are you defining GetText?

Comment: I don't remember about GetText, it was two years ago after all. I'm not sure if it is possible to add property to property map in source, I remember I still can't find solution for it.

Comment: What I am suggesting is to create your own ActiveX control as a new project and implement the functionality using the Bacs_DBTableRepX class as base or a class member.